# How to access to userDefined or ExtendedProperties data of a User in Directory API

Tags: google-contacts-api, google-admin-sdk, google-provisioning-api

Since the Google Apps Profiles API has been officially deprecated. It has been replaced by the Directory API.
The fields (Organizations, Phones numbers, ...) of a ContactEntry (Apps Profiles API) exists in the User (Directory API).

But I cannot find the UserDefinedFields and ExtendedProperties fields in the User of Directory API ?

How can I have access to these kinds of data ?

Comment: "extendedProperty" is supported by contacts API. Even profiles API dosent support it.  check this  "Also note that the Profile kind, unlike the Contact kind, does not support gd:extendedProperty" (from https://developers.google.com/google-apps/profiles/reference). So, even in directory API you wont find this field.

Comment: I agree with the extendedProperty. But as it is noticed in this link (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/migrate#user_accounts_and_multi-domain_users), The User feed exposed by the Provisining API to manage user accounts has been replaced by the Users resource in the Directory API. But nothing is written about the field UserDefinedField.

Answer (score 0):

The Directory API exposes custom Schemas.  Your app can create a Schema object and define the fields supported by that schema.  Then you can include json to set fields in that schema.  However, the fields are associated with that schema.  The intent appears to be to expose those fields to custom apps, not as part of the data shown for a user in the Contacts Directory.  If you had code which set UserDefinedFields on a user's profile object and were visible in the Contacts directory those fields are not visible to the Directory API.  It also appears that you can't use Directory API Schemas to add user defined fields to a User that will show up on their profile view in Contacts Directory.

Comment: The UserDefinedFields on a user's profile object are visible in the Contacts directory but not visible to the Directory API. It was visible to the Profiles API now deprecated. I have data on these fields that are useless, but they still appear in the contact directory. So now how is it possible delete them ?